# Removing selected node from xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf

I am trying to make some music library app for my classes. I've done pretty much everything i had to but there is one thing left. I don't know how to access data from data template generated item to delete both this item form app and xml node from xml file.

I have found this bit of code that should delete the node i want but i still don't know how to access data from item that i selected.

```
private void DeleteFromFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(@"musicLibrary.xml");
        foreach(XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("musicLibrary"))
        {
            if(xNode.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText == "")
            {
                xNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

the nodes looks like this:

```
  <musicLibrary>
<title>I Still Haven't Found What I'm Looking For</title>
<albumName>The Joshua Tree</albumName>
<artist>U2</artist>
<releaseDate>1987</releaseDate>
<tempo>101</tempo>
<duration>4:37</duration>
<genre>Rock</genre>
  </musicLibrary>
  <musicLibrary>
<title>Magnificent</title>
<albumName>No Line on the Horizon</albumName>
<artist>U2</artist>
<releaseDate>2009</releaseDate>
<tempo>115</tempo>
<duration>5:24</duration>
<genre>Rock</genre>
  </musicLibrary>
```

data templates that i use:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="listDataView"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="mDataTamplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="5" Text="{Binding title}" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="10" Margin="5" Text="{Binding artist}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="detailedDataTamplate">
        <Grid  Grid.Row="3" Margin="20,0,20,0">
            <!-- Row/Column Definition-->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- First Column -->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Title" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}" />
            <TextBlock         Text="{Binding title}"
                               Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  
                               Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Album name" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock         Text="{Binding albumName}" 
                               Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  
                               Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Artist" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock         Text="{Binding artist}"  
                               Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  
                               Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Release Date" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock         Text="{Binding releaseDate}"   
                               Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  
                               Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <!-- Second Column -->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Tempo" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding tempo}" 
                                Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"
                                Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Duration" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" 
                       Text="{Binding duration}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="Genre" Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" 
                       Text="{Binding genre}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>

            <Button x:Name="saveToFile" Click="saveToFile_Click" Content="Save to file"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="31"/>
            <Button x:Name="deleteFromFile" Click="DeleteFromFile_Click" Content="Delete" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

And class that i bind data from:

```
namespace MLUI
 {
[XmlRoot("dataSet")]
public class DataSet
{
    [XmlElement("musicLibrary")]
    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
public class Song
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("artist")]
    public string artist { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("albumName")]
    public string albumName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("releaseDate")]
    public string releaseDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("tempo")]
    public int tempo { get; set; }        
    [XmlElement("duration")]
    public string duration { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("genre")]
    public string genre { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Title:  " + title +"\r\nArtist:  "+ artist +"\r\nAlbum Name:  "+ albumName + "\r\nRelease Date:  " + releaseDate +
            "\r\nTempo  "+ tempo + "\r\nDuration  " + duration + "\r\nGenre  " + genre ;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the inner text to one of the titles? best way to go about this if you are not sure is to put a bp in the if, go to the inmediate window and play with the variables

Comment: i don't get what are you suggesting. I wanted to delete item that i clicked at in app. Also i don't know how to delete this data template generated item in app.

Comment: well thats what im telling you, you need to set that inner text to something != from "" . It wont ever enter that if statement if you dont

Comment: Doesn't this: (xNode.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText mean that i am selecting inner text of title node? Or maybe you mean that i need to compare it with something? If that is what you mean then i know that. The only thing that i don't know is how to get title of item that i selected and then compare it to every title in xml file to find this one i am looking for to delete.

Comment: Personally, i would serialise/deserialise classes to xml files. All you need is a public class with public properties and datacontractserialiser.  You then work with csharp collections  internally and don't need to even consider the xml aspect of things beyond two methods. Read and save.

Answer (score 0):

I like using Xml Linq with a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement dataSet = doc.Root;

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dictionary = dataSet.Elements("musicLibrary")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("title"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            XElement Magnificent = dictionary["Magnificent"];

            Magnificent.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```